# JavaScript DataStructures

Tags: javascript

Is there any good learning book on JavaScript Data Structures, something like this.

http://www.cs.williams.edu/javastructures/Book_files/JavaStructures.pdf

I am unable to find anyting on internet.

Comment: Data Structures are just a part of learning JS. Try [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do).

Comment: DCoder's suggestion + [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) and you're pretty much set.

Comment: <a href="http://www.datajett.com/Tuts/JScriptGen/javascriptDataStructs.pdf">this may help </a> I found this is a good pdf

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention your level of JavaScript knowledge, so I assume you're fresh. ) In that case I suggest reading [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) online book; [this chapter](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) in particular will answer your question, but I suppose reading the whole book would be a great experience as well.

But not reading only: in fact, I regard this book highly because it provides tremendous environment for experiments with code given. And practice, in my opinion, is the only real key to understanding anything related to CS. )

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links

[One](http://www.datajett.com/Tuts/JScriptGen/javascriptDataStructs.pdf)

[Two](http://www3.amherst.edu/~aanderson/javascript/datastructures/)

[Three](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html)

And one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167030/major-javascript-data-structures) on SO explaining about data structures in js